# How do find out what libraries a windows exe uses?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a 3rd party application that doesn't come with an installer.  It's a very small exe, a simulator.

Anyhow, it crashes on startup due to some missing libraries.  But the error doesn't tell me which ones.  Is there an application on windows that tells me which libraries are going to be loaded at program load time?

Comment: `tasklist /m` can show all loaded modules. I am not sure if it exists on XP. BTW: you better ask this on superuser.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's been a few years since i've used it but [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) got me through a lot of DLL hell.

Also, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is a great and fast way to see what DLLs are loaded by an EXE on a test machine... for comparison purposes when hunting down missing DLLs.

Comment: I use dependency walker myself.

Comment: Dependancy walker did the trick.  Once I got some of the DLL's on there I discovered it needed the dot net runtime.  Once I installed that all was well.

Comment: Ten years later and it is Dependency Walker, still works.

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer: DEPENDS.EXE tells you what dlls a dll needs.  I think it works for EXE's too.